# Alternative to jquery $(document).ready(handler) when using javascript page transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, transition

In a simple plugin for my wordpress site, I wrote code that sets up click events as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        //do stuff
    });
});
```

This code works as expected when I load the relevant page ***directly.*** However, the way users are expected to access the page is through a link in the theme header. I am not really sure how page transitions in the theme work, but the end effect is that whenever a link is clicked, some animation happens, the page fades out, and the new page fades in. The problem is that $(document).ready() does not fire when the new page fades in, so the click handlers do not function.

How can I change the code so that the click handlers are registered at the time the new page fades in?

If it's necessary to see how the theme works, I am using the Bridge Theme. A demo version of the theme is available [here](http://demo.qodeinteractive.com/bridge/).

UPDATE:
After playing with the theme page transitions a bit, I am suspecting that the theme is using ajax to get the new page content, fading out old page content, fading in new page content, then "artificially" modifying the url to show the new pages url.

Comment: Can you simply do something like this? `$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() { /* ... */ })`

Comment: @Evilzebra, I guess the problem is that at the time of page load there are no DOM elements with id "myButton." Even if there is a significant difference between using .click(function()) and on('click','selector',function()), I would need the button to exist before running the code.

Comment: `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {` might help - it is triggered by jquery each time an ajax function completes.

Comment: @sideroxylon, that's really close to what I think the solution will be (and a great tool I didn't know about). The problem I am having with it is that It seems the ajaxComplete function fires right when the data has been received for the new page (but still has not been added to the DOM). I've tested this using the chrome debugger and confirmed the new content is not yet in the DOM when ajaxComplete fires. I'm considering using setTimeout to delay my code just long enough for the content to show up, as much as I hate that solution.

Comment: Rather than a time out, maybe just bind the click function to the body - `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { $('body').on('click', '#myButton', function() {`.  A time out might work, but the delay is likely to be variable.

Comment: Looks like I dismissed @Evilzebra's suggestion too quickly. It works. I'm guessing this is because using $(document).on('click',selector,handler) allows you to register a click handler without the selector matching anything in the DOM.

Comment: Also, your suggestion works too, @sideroxylon. It wasn't until I looked at why it worked, that I realized that Evilzebra's solution would probably work as well.

Comment: Yes, you originally missed the point of @Evilzebra's comment above.  Their version of the code is precisely how you'd construct a handler for an element that does not exist when the handler is called.  ~ [*"**Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time."*](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind your click event to the document it will apply to elements which are loaded or created after the document has loaded.

This can be done like so:

`$(document).on('click', '#myButton', function() { /* ... */ });`

Comment: The correct answer.  Perhaps improve it by using the proper terminology and linking to the documentation.  [**"Delegated events"**](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score -1):

you can use one of these methods:

- The DOM way

  window.onload = function() { // do stuff with the DOM }
- The direct jQuery translation

  $(document).ready(function() { // do stuff with the DOM });
- The jQuery way

  $(function() { // do stuff with the DOM });

Comment: Your three descriptions are nonsense.  The first one fires as soon as the DOM **and** all page assets have finished loading.  Your second and third bullet items are functionally the same, both DOM ready handlers, and fire as soon as the DOM is ready.  See:  https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler